# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ANT build

Tags: java, xml, selenium, ant, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error regarding the classpath in the run stage. The error is

```
run:
    [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    [java]  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    [java]  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    [java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  ... 7 more
    [java] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    [java] Exception in thread "main" 
    [java] Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

This is the xml build code I have written. I am referencing the RunningPower jars folder and I believe the correct folder is being referenced as i able am able to compile. My base directory also contains a .classpath and .project file but not sure if they are important.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<project name="SeleniumProjectDataDriven" basedir="." default="run">
    <target name="init">
        <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
        <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
        <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/class" />
        <property name="lib.dir" value="RunningPowerJars" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="init">
         <delete dir="build"/>
     </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the code" depends="clean" >
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" description="Packages the code into jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
            <jar destfile="build/jar/RunningPower.jar" basedir="build/class">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="RunningPower"/>
                </manifest> 
            </jar> 
    </target>

    <target name="run" description="Run the jar file" depends="jar" >
        <java jar="build/jar/RunningPower.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

In my RunningPowerJars folder, they contain

```
junit-4.8.1.jar
ojdbc6.jar
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
selenium-java-2.46.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar
testng-6.1.1.jar
```

Update (7:32 AM PST 8/21/2015)

```
<target name="run" description="Run the jar file" depends="jar" >
    <java jar="build/jar/RunningPower.jar" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" /> 
            </fileset> 
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

I modified the code but ran into another error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dt208672\Perforce\depot\ebill\Automation\Selenium_eBill\RunningPower\build.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classpath is needed also when running the Jar file so that the JVM could find library classes. However, when using the `jar` attribute in the `java` task, *"all classpath settings are ignored"* (see https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html). The simplest way is to specify the main class and add the compiled Jar along with the library Jars located in the `RunningPowerJars` directory:

```
<target name="run" description="Run the jar file" depends="jar" >
    <java classname="RunningPower" fork="true">
       <classpath>
            <pathelement location="build/jar/RunningPower.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
   </java>
</target>
```

An unrelated note is that you could use the properties defined in `init` throughout the buildfile. For example, in the `jar` target you can use `${classes.dir}` instead of repeating `build/class`.

It still doesn't make sense why the build would fail if the `classpath` element is added inside the `java` task when using the `jar` attribute. Although it is ignored, it is weird that it is failing with the "failed to create task or type" error.

Comment: @LinhSaysHi You didn't update correctly. The `classpath` should be _inside_ the `java` element.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry about that! However the same error still occurs

Comment: @LinhSaysHi I updated the answer. `classpath` is actually ignored when using the `jar` attribute in the `java` task. Still, however, it's weird that it fails with that error.

Comment: Might be something else. I will give it a look today. Thank you so much for putting in the time to help me

Answer (score 0):

Consider that when you use the -jar parameter using the java.exe in command line the classpath parameter is ignored, that also happens with the java task in ant.

So, what you must do is to provide the libraries you need to have available to the process launching that ant and that will suffice.

Once said that... where should you add those libraries then ? if you're launching from eclipse, you may add them on Window->preferences under Ant->Runtime->Global Entries.

If you're using some C.I. server like jenkins you could add them on numerous ways, I cannot give a direct answer because there could be many.

There is also an alternative. You may declare the dependency on the .jar MANIFEST.MF and put it under /lib or whatever inside that jar.